# Adding Theme File for Non-Wordpress Content

Tags: url-rewriting, customization, 404-error

I have a third party events plugin that uses custom tables in the database. I have created a theme file (event.php) that pulls the data in based on a slug that is ideally given in the URL.

I want to create a custom URL rewrite rule for this template, so a URL like this:

/event/my-slug

Will call the event.php file, grabbing the specific event they have requested (the slug).

The class I am including in the functions.php to accomplish this is:

```
<?php 
$EventpageCode = new Eventpage();
register_activation_hook( __file__, array($EventpageCode, 'activate') );

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', array($EventpageCode, 'create_rewrite_rules'));
add_filter('query_vars',array($EventpageCode, 'add_query_vars'));

add_filter('admin_init', array($EventpageCode, 'flush_rewrite_rules'));
add_action('template_include', array($EventpageCode, 'template_redirect_intercept'));

class Eventpage {

    function activate() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $this->flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    function create_rewrite_rules($rules) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $newRule = array('event/(.+)' => 'index.php?pagename=event&eventid='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1));
        $newRules = $newRule + $rules;
        return $newRules;
    }

    function add_query_vars($qvars) {
        $qvars[] = 'eventid';
        return $qvars;
    }

    function flush_rewrite_rules() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }

    function template_redirect_intercept($template) {
        global $wp_query;
        if ($wp_query->get('eventid')) {
            $template = locate_template( array( 'event.php' ) );
        }
        return $template;
    }

    function pushoutput($message) {
        $this->output($message);
    }

    function output( $output ) {
        header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' );
        header( 'Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );

        echo json_encode( $output );
    }
}
?>
```

This works great for displaying the content, except that the page throws a 404 error (but still displays the content). Any suggestions on how to avoid having the 404 error returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove *pagename=event&* and reset your rewrite rules...

```
$newRule = array('event/(.+)' => 'index.php?eventid='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1));
```

---

*template_include* is a **filter** NOT an action!

```
add_filter('template_include', array($EventpageCode, 'template_redirect_intercept'));
```

---

You can use *wp_title* [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) or [filter](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/general-template.php.source.html#l609) to modify your page title.